# How can i know the number of elements in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I know that len(dict) would give the number of keys but what i want is this

```
 mydict = {
    'a': [[2,4], [5,6]],
    'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9], [6,2,3]],
    'c': [['a'], [4,5]],
}
```

The number i want in this case is 7, 7 being the number of elements in 'a' + number of elements in 'b' + number of elements in 'c'

Comment: `nb = sum([len(value) for value in dict.values()])` ?

Comment: Is that even a valid dict?

Comment: `sum(map(len, mydict.values()))`

Comment: @IMCoins i got the following error `TypeError: 'nb' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: @DavidG no it probably isn't just an example to explain my issue.

Comment: @khelwood kindly add it in answers so i can accept it.

Comment: Also, don't name your variable `dict`, since you're shadowing a builtin name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a dictionary

```
mydict = {
    'a': [[2,4], [5,6]],
    'b': [[1,1], [1,7,9], [6,2,3]],
    'c': [['a'], [4,5]],
}
```

You can get the sum of the lengths of each value using

```
sum(map(len, mydict.values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Please correct your example, it is not valid python dict.

I assumed that against every key you have list of lists.

```
dict = {
        'a': [[2,4],[5,6]],
        'b': [[1,1],[1,7,9],[6,2,3]],
        'c': [[3],[4,5]]
}
```

Your answer:

```
print sum (len(element) for element in dict.values());
```

Comment: Are you sure `mydict` is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not a valid python dictionary.

This is a valid dictionary:

```
dict = {
        'a': ([2,4],[5,6]),
        'b': ([1,1],[1,7,9],[6,2,3]),
        'c': ([a],[4,5])
}
```

Use tuples to group multi-value items with fixed size (they have better performance than lists).

The answer to the question, using the correct dictionary, is

```
sum([len(e) for e in dict.values()])
```